# External stylesheet doesen't link

Tags: html

i am trying to link a stylesheet in another file. I've tried everything, copied it from multiple websites. But it doesen't seem to work. The css doesen't load any way. This is probably a really dumb mistake somewhere. Maybe it just needs another pair of eyes. The css works fine, what is causing problems is the link tag. What i noticed is, when i try to go to `http://localhost:8080/styles.css` it gives me `Cannot GET /styles.css` in plain text. I've tried modifying the permissions of the files, doesen't work. The filename is correct.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test zabezpečení prohlížeče</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1 id="page-title">Test zabezpečení prohlížeče</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `styles.css` is not external, `bootstrap.min.css` would be external. Do you get a 404? If you curl the resource does it resolve for you?

Comment: Your stylesheet is probably in a sub-directory ..  IE `/media/style.css` or `/assets/styles.css` ..  You need to be sure you are linking to the correct path to `styles.css`

Comment: Does the web server have a log file that you can examine to see if the correct URL is sent to the server?

Comment: If i curl /styles.css it still says the same thing. It's not in a subdirectory. It's nodejs express so i can't get a log.